# jqgrid infinite scroll paging

Tags: jqgrid, infinite-scroll

I was wondering if there was some way to implement infinite scroll paging with jqgrid and its tabletogrid extension?  I know you can implement regular paging with jqgrid, but would I need a different tool to do infinite scroll?

Comment: Could you explain more detailed what you mean under "infinite scroll". Especially unclear it's for me in the combination with `tableToGrid` which can be used to convert HTML `<table>` to jqGrid having `datatype: "local"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a while ago, but you can find a sample under http://trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html under the section "new in version 3.4"

and a newer one under 3.7 "virtual scrolling"

Answer (score 0):

Use jqgrid option scroll: true for infinite scroll pages.

```
.jqGrid({
            datatype : "local",
            data : JSONData,
            height : ($(window).height() - 250),
            width : ($(window).width() - 32),
            scroll : true, 
            rowNum:20, // the number of row's to be displayed the first time
...
..
});
```

check http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:options
look scroll -- option.

Answer (score 0):

.jqGrid({
         scroll: 1,
});

by setting option to scroll